# CTS-Search unique element values for specific attribute

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm looking for a search routine to give me a list of all unique values of element Brand with attribute 'Heineken'. So in this case; Can, Crate.

I try to do this:

```
let $query := cts:element-attribute-values(xs:QName("p:brand"), xs:QName("name"), 'Heineken')

for $temp in cts:search(fn:doc(), (cts:query($query)))

return fn:distinct-values($temp)
```

For this I create a: range element attribute index on brand/name.

My ultimate goal is to create a list of unique values of Merlot for every document with Heineken/Can. In the example below; Glass.

---

saturday.xml

```
<thedrinksihad>
    <brand name='Heineken'>Can</brand>
    <brand name='Grolsch'>Bottle</brand>
    <brand name='Merlot'>Glass</brand>
</thedrinksihad>
```

---

sunday.xml

```
<thedrinksihad>
    <brand name='Heineken'>Crate</brand>
    <brand name='Grolsch'>Can</brand>
    <brand name='Merlot'>Bottle</brand>
</thedrinksihad>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably several ways to do this, but since you are starting out using a range index, this answer will use them. You'll need another range index on `xs:QName('p:brand')`.

This query will return all of the documents that contain a `<brand name='Heineken'>Can</brand>` and any `<brand name='Merlot'>`. Then it filters the output to select only the `Merlot` brands and takes the `distinct-values` of that sequence:

```
let $merlots :=
  cts:search(//p:thedrinksihad,
      cts:and-query((
        cts:element-query(xs:QName('p:brand'),
          cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("p:brand"), xs:QName("name"), '=', 'Merlot')),
        cts:element-query(xs:QName('p:brand'),
          cts:and-query((
            cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("p:brand"), xs:QName("name"), '=', 'Heineken'),
            cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("p:brand"), '=', 'can'))))
      ))
    )/p:thedrinksihad/p:brand[@name eq 'Merlot']
return distinct-values($merlots)
```

Just a note that `cts:*-values` functions can be tricky. This is a scenario where it seems like it might be ideal, since they only return distinct values. However, the query passed to a  `cts:*-values` function runs "unfiltered", which means it will return all values from any matching fragments. In this case that means all the `<brand>` values in a matching doc, including ones besides those from `<brand name='Merlot'>`.